# Removing a Group while Calculating Quartiles

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table named `df`:

```
Year    Vendor  Class1  Class2  SKU Rate    Q1
Year 2  A       R       F       195 0.10    0.060
Year 2  B       R       F       592 0.06    0.120
Year 2  C       R       F       597 0.19    0.055
Year 2  C       R       F       337 0.12    0.055
Year 2  B       R       F       881 0.04    0.120
Year 2  A       R       F       720 0.29    0.060
Year 2  C       R       F       636 0.12    0.055
Year 2  B       L       T       246 0.04    0.030
Year 2  B       L       T       440 0.02    0.030
Year 2  A       L       T       560 0.03    0.030
Year 2  B       L       T       425 0.03    0.030
Year 2  C       L       T       325 0.03    0.028
Year 2  C       L       T       745 0.03    0.028
Year 2  A       R       S       934 0.02    0.140
Year 2  C       R       S       233 0.14    0.020
Year 3  A       R       F       195 0.14    0.080
Year 3  B       R       F       592 0.08    0.180
Year 3  C       R       F       597 0.29    0.075
Year 3  C       R       F       337 0.18    0.075
Year 3  B       R       F       881 0.06    0.180
Year 3  A       R       F       720 0.41    0.080
Year 3  C       R       F       636 0.22    0.075
Year 3  B       L       T       246 0.06    0.050
Year 3  B       L       T       440 0.04    0.050
Year 3  A       L       T       560 0.05    0.050
Year 3  B       L       T       425 0.06    0.050
Year 3  C       L       T       325 0.05    0.050
Year 3  C       L       T       745 0.05    0.050
Year 3  A       R       S       934 0.03    0.040
Year 3  C       R       S       233 0.04    0.030
```

Using the `Rate` for each `SKU`, I'm trying to calculate the 1st quartile for each Year/Vendor/Class1/Class2 Combination.

Normally calculating the quartile would be trivial, however, to remove bias among the Vendors for the groupings, I want to remove the respective vendor from a group.

For example, If I'm calculating the quartile for SKU 195 for Vendor A, I want to calculate the quartile using SKUs 592, 597, 337, 991, 636. (The SKUs for vendors B and C for Year 2, and Class2 = F. When I calculate the quartile for SKU 592 for Vendor B, I only want to calculate using SKUs 195, 597, 337, 720, 636 for Vendors A and C only Year = 2 and Class2 = F.

There are many more Vendors and Classes, but this should provide enough context and sample to show what I'm trying to do. I manually calculated the Q1 column in `df` to show what I'm looking for.

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to be removing the Vendor_Selected from the Quartile calculation like I had hoped.

```
VAR
Vendor_Selected = SELECTEDVALUE(df[Vendor])
RETURN
    SUMMARIZE(
        df, 
        df[Year], 
        df[Vendor], 
        df[Class1], 
        df[Class2], 
        "Q1", 
            CALCULATE(PERCENTILE.INC(
                df[Rate]. 0.25), 
                Vendor_Selected <> df[Vendor]
            )
    )
```

I know this is a pretty unique way to calculate quartile but I have 5,000+ records and I've been stuck on this all day.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't clearly understand this part :**Normally this would be trivial, however, to remove bias among the Vendors, when I calculate the quartile for Vendor A, I want to calculate the quartile for vendors B and C for each given Year and Class2. When I calculate the quartile for Vendor B, I only want to calculate using Vendors A and C only for a given Year and Class2.**

But I understood this :**Using the Rate for each SKU, I'm trying to calculate the 1st quartile for each Year/Vendor/Class1/Class2 Combination.**

So here's my solution :

```
Quartile rank  = PERCENTILEX.INC(FILTER(FILTER(
FILTER(
FILTER('tablename',
[Year] = EARLIER([Year])
),
[Vendor] = EARLIER([Vendor]),
[CLASS1] = EARLIER([CLASS1]),
[CLASS2] = EARLIER([CLASS2])
,[RATE],.25)
```

If you want to include only B and C while calculating quartiles of A (as I understood ) you could put an if condition to select only B and C and then do the percentilex function.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I edited the question to be a little more clear.

Comment: Okay I think you can achieve this using an if condition and allexcept with percentilex . Also try combining it all using Calculate.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've tried some pf those combinations with ALLEXCEPT, CALCULATE, etc. I'm still not finding the proper syntax how to compute.